# BPMN diagram about two swimlanes or one or two pools

Tags: bpmn

I have a question. suppose we wanna a BPMN diagram for transferring soccer player from team A in country A to team B in country B and to do that the federation of A should cancel the player registeration for team A and federation B should accept registeration for team B.
my question is that if we should have two swimlane with role federation A and B or one swimlane is enough? or also we have to had two pools ?
Please help me for this question. thanks a lot

Comment: please have a look at my answer and provide me with some feedback so that we could close this issue for you and for anyone who might come across this in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach depends a lot on what you are modelling and why. I will give you an example of motivation for each of the mentioned methods so that you could get the idea and make the right choice yourself.

1. You don't really care about who does what in your scenario and the main point is the order of actions and exceptions. No swimlanes are needed, just put your diagram out there:
   [image: pic1]
2. Your scenario is whole and should never be decomposed into parts (e. g. Cancellation and Registration) because there is very little or none at all sense in looking at the parts on their own. Make one pool with two or three (possibly for the player himself) swimlanes:
   [image]
3. Your scenario can be decomposed and it makes good sense. The process occasionally stops at a point of Cancellation (without new Registration).
   Use different pools with separate process flows:
   [image]
   Also, use a separate Blackbox Pool if you don't know what a participant (a player or a federation) actually does and you can only communicate with it by some kind of messaging (e. g. `-Accept?` `-OK`).